# Why squatting leads to decrease in MVP murmur

Tags: heart, cardiac-physiology

Mvp = mitral valve prolapse
Hcm = hypertrophic cardiomyopathy

Now, I understand that during squatting preload and afterload will increase and both of them would lead to increased LV volume, but how come they would decrease MVP and HCM murmur shouldn't that increase? shouldn't that cause more of parachuting of the prolapsed valve, okay I understand about the HCM that the blood in ventricles displaces the septum but I cannot understand about the MVP.

Comment: Some punctuation and capitalization would be welcome.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The murmur from HOCM is from the mitral valve leaflet jamming into the septum, also called systolic anterior motion (SAM). This disappears when you increase the volume of LV because if you increase the volume, the ventricle becomes more distended and the leaflet is further away from the septum, so you have less murmur that can be heard.

MVP murmur decreases during squatting because if you increase the volume in LV, there is more tension on the chordae tendinae so the leaflets can't prolapse as much.